# Appending columns to a new dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
df =

    0   1   2   3   4
0   0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1
1   0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1
2   0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1
3   0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1
```

And a list of lists that looks like this.

```
dir = [[0,1,2],[3,4]]
```

What I want to do is to create a new empty dataframe and fill it with appended columns as per the list. To do this, I will need to loop through the list of lists and append the corresponding columns. Here is the desired output:

```
    0    1
0   0.5  0.2
1   0.5  0.2
2   0.5  0.2
3   0.5  0.2
4   0.4  0.1
5   0.4  0.1
6   0.4  0.1
7   0.4  0.1
8   0.3
9   0.3
10  0.3
11  0.3
```

Here is my code attempt:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in dir:
    for j in i:
        new_df.append([df[i]])
```

However overwrites the new dataframe each time instead of appending and also appends the data as a row instead of a column.

***EDIT***
The following solution worked well for a list of lists of equal length:

```
L = [[0,1],[2,3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([df[x].values.T.ravel()[:, None] for x in L]))
print (df)
```

However I need a solution which can handle lists of varying length (i.e list = [ [0,1,2], [3,4] ])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for prevent align columns by columns names with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [[0,1],[2,3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([df[x].values.T.ravel()[:, None] for x in L]))
print (df)

     0    1
0  0.5  0.3
1  0.5  0.3
2  0.5  0.3
3  0.5  0.3
4  0.4  0.2
5  0.4  0.2
6  0.4  0.2
7  0.4  0.2
```

EDIT: For general solution create `Series` and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
L = [[0,1,2],[3,4]] 

df = pd.concat([pd.Series(df[x].values.T.ravel()) for x in L], axis=1)
print (df)
      0    1
0   0.5  0.2
1   0.5  0.2
2   0.5  0.2
3   0.5  0.2
4   0.4  0.1
5   0.4  0.1
6   0.4  0.1
7   0.4  0.1
8   0.3  NaN
9   0.3  NaN
10  0.3  NaN
11  0.3  NaN
```

Comment: Maybe , I think ,just minor structure adjust can match the expected output of op.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df[x].values.T.ravel() for x in l]).T)
`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael these work well for the example. But will this work for a list that contains something like this: list = [ [0,1,2], [3,4], [5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12] ] ?

Comment: Same question for your solution @Wen :) Will it work for a list of lists with a different shape?

Answer (score 2):

Using `melt`

```
l=[[0,1],[2,3]]
d={x : df[y].melt().value.tolist()  for x,y in enumerate(l)}
pd.DataFrame(d)
Out[171]: 
     0    1
0  0.5  0.3
1  0.5  0.3
2  0.5  0.3
3  0.5  0.3
4  0.4  0.2
5  0.4  0.2
6  0.4  0.2
7  0.4  0.2
```

Comment: Thanks @Wen this works well for the example given. How would this need to change to accept a list of lists with varying lengths? E.g list = [ [0,1,2], [3,4], [5], [6,7] ]